# Class access modifier

Tags: java, eclipse

I have the following two classes

```
package one;
public class Student
{
    //Some code
}

package two;
public class Test
{ 
     public static void main(String args[])
     {
           Student s = new Student();
           //Some code
      }
 }
```

Even though the "Student" class has public access modifier, whenever I try to create an object for the Student class, in the Test class, which is from another package, eclipse points out error saying either I need to import the student class or create a new class.

I thought if a class is declared public, it can be accessed from any where. But why does eclipse call it an error?

Comment: use the same package

Comment: Use the fully qualified name: `one.Student`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have an `import` statement, so the compiler doesn't know that `Student` is meant to refer to `one.Student`. You can either use:

```
import one.Student;
```

or

```
import one.*;
```

... or just fully-qualify the name when you create the object:

```
one.Student s = new one.Student();
```

This isn't a matter of accessibility - it's the compiler not knowing how to resolve the identifier `Student` into a fully-qualified class name.

Answer (score 0):

If the class is in another package, you need to import it, like this

```
import one.Student;
```

and then you will able to use it. This is to avoid ambiguity if any other class in the build path has the same name.

Answer (score 0):

If a class is public it means you can use it outside its package in another package. You sill need to import the class though.

```
import one.Student
```

If a class is package private it can be used within the same package but cannot be imported by other packages